# Postgres alter system command fails using Hibernate fails

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I want to make a change to the postgres.conf file at runtime. However, when I execute the sql with "alter system" via hibernate I get an error

> Transaction is marked for rollback only or has timed out

I think this has something to do with alter system commands not allowed to execute inside a transaction block as per the documentation

> Only superusers can use ALTER SYSTEM. Also, since this command acts directly on the file system and cannot be rolled back, it is not allowed inside a transaction block or function.

Im trying to understand if its possible to execute this type of command with hibernate and what I need to do to be able to do that?

Comment: Well, as the error message tells you: only a superuser (typically `postgres`)  is allowed to run ALTER SYSTEM. I would not allow a "regular" application on a production server that requires superuser privileges to run - it's like requiring a desktop app to be run as `root` so that it can mess around with the system configuration. That would be a huge security risk. Changes  to `postgresql.conf` should not be done by the application, that's the job of the DBA

Comment: Thats not the issue here, I can use this command fine and the privileges are not the issue.

Comment: I think you are confusing the documentation with an error message, the first quote is an error, the second is the documentation.

Comment: You could just retrieve a JDBC connection from your datasource, set that to auto-commit, execute the query, reset the auto-commit flag and finally close the connection.